# Executor ThreadPool, garbage collection

Tags: garbage-collection, threadpoolexecutor

I am using ThreadPool executor in a do while loop as a deamon process.
At the start of every iteration i am creating newFixedThreadPool:
    executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

After the task gets finished, i am calling shutdown before the next iteration starts and the newFixedPool gets created for new 5 worker Threads.

Now while printing Log4J logs. I am using [%t] to show which threadpool getting executed.
I see for every iteration new threadpool getting created with an incremented number.

Please let me know do i need to call executor=null, before starting the next iteration?

Is the incremented threadpool indicates, threadpool getting accumulated and may result to memory leak as it's a deamon process or in the back end threadpool will be garbage collected as all threads have been completed and we already executed shutdown.

```
 2014-06-26 16:26:11,548 [47    ] [INFO ][pool-1-thread-1] - Started processing new         payments for serverID: 5
2014-06-26 16:26:11,548 [47    ] [INFO ][pool-1-thread-2] - Started processing new payments for serverID: 6
2014-06-26 16:26:11,548 [47    ] [INFO ][pool-1-thread-3] - Started processing new payments for serverID: 7
2014-06-26 16:26:11,548 [47    ] [INFO ][pool-1-thread-4] - Started processing new payments for serverID: 8
2014-06-26 16:26:11,548 [47    ] [INFO ][pool-1-thread-5] - Started processing new payments for serverID: 9
2014-06-26 16:26:24,129 [12628 ] [INFO ][pool-1-thread-2] - Completed processing new payments for serverID: 6
2014-06-26 16:26:24,129 [12628 ] [INFO ][pool-1-thread-5] - Completed processing new payments for serverID: 9
2014-06-26 16:26:24,129 [12628 ] [INFO ][pool-1-thread-2] - Time taken to Process new payments for serverId 6 : 12 Sec 
2014-06-26 16:26:24,129 [12628 ] [INFO ][pool-1-thread-5] - Time taken to Process new payments for serverId 9 : 12 Sec 
2014-06-26 16:26:24,129 [12628 ] [INFO ][pool-1-thread-3] - Completed processing new payments for serverID: 7
2014-06-26 16:26:24,129 [12628 ] [INFO ][pool-1-thread-1] - Completed processing new payments for serverID: 5
2014-06-26 16:26:24,129 [12628 ] [INFO ][pool-1-thread-3] - Time taken to Process new payments for serverId 7 : 12 Sec 
2014-06-26 16:26:24,129 [12628 ] [INFO ][pool-1-thread-1] - Time taken to Process new payments for serverId 5 : 12 Sec 
2014-06-26 16:26:24,129 [12628 ] [INFO ][pool-1-thread-4] - Completed processing new payments for serverID: 8
2014-06-26 16:26:24,129 [12628 ] [INFO ][pool-1-thread-4] - Time taken to Process new payments for serverId 8 : 12 Sec 
2014-06-26 16:26:24,129 [12628 ] [INFO ][main] - ShutDown complete
2014-06-26 16:26:24,129 [12628 ] [INFO ][main] - ProcessDeamon iteration finished in 0 Sec 
2014-06-26 16:26:24,129 [12628 ] [INFO ][main] - ProcessDeamon iteration started
2014-06-26 16:26:24,191 [12690 ] [INFO ][pool-2-thread-1] - Started processing new payments for serverID: 5
2014-06-26 16:26:24,191 [12690 ] [INFO ][pool-2-thread-2] - Started processing new payments for serverID: 6
2014-06-26 16:26:24,191 [12690 ] [INFO ][pool-2-thread-3] - Started processing new payments for serverID: 7
2014-06-26 16:26:24,191 [12690 ] [INFO ][pool-2-thread-4] - Started processing new payments for serverID: 8
2014-06-26 16:26:24,191 [12690 ] [INFO ][pool-2-thread-5] - Started processing new payments for serverID: 9

2014-06-26 16:26:34,443 [22942 ] [INFO ][pool-2-thread-2] - Completed processing new payments for serverID: 6
2014-06-26 16:26:34,443 [22942 ] [INFO ][pool-2-thread-2] - Time taken to Process new payments for serverId 6 : 10 Sec 
2014-06-26 16:26:34,490 [22989 ] [INFO ][pool-2-thread-4] - Completed processing new payments for serverID: 8
2014-06-26 16:26:34,490 [22989 ] [INFO ][pool-2-thread-3] - Completed processing new payments for serverID: 7
2014-06-26 16:26:34,490 [22989 ] [INFO ][pool-2-thread-5] - Completed processing new payments for serverID: 9
2014-06-26 16:26:34,490 [22989 ] [INFO ][pool-2-thread-4] - Time taken to Process new payments for serverId 8 : 10 Sec 
2014-06-26 16:26:34,490 [22989 ] [INFO ][pool-2-thread-3] - Time taken to Process new payments for serverId 7 : 10 Sec 
2014-06-26 16:26:34,490 [22989 ] [INFO ][pool-2-thread-5] - Time taken to Process new payments for serverId 9 : 10 Sec 
2014-06-26 16:26:34,521 [23020 ] [INFO ][pool-2-thread-1] - Completed processing new payments for serverID: 5
2014-06-26 16:26:34,521 [23020 ] [INFO ][pool-2-thread-1] - Time taken to Process new payments for serverId 5 : 10 Sec 
2014-06-26 16:26:34,521 [23020 ] [INFO ][main] - ShutDown complete
2014-06-26 16:26:34,521 [23020 ] [INFO ][main] - ProcessDeamon iteration finished in 0 Sec 
2014-06-26 16:26:34,521 [23020 ] [INFO ][main] - ProcessDeamon iteration started
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not shutdown your Threadpool but re-use it. That's the whole point in having a Threadpool: You submit Tasks into this pool and do not have to care about the thread-management. Just wait for your threads to terminate and submit the next batch of tasks into the same pool.

Comment: I can't reuse...as i want all iterations to be consistent. That is the reason, i m calling shutdown...and then waiting in indefinite loop to check if executor is terminated. After executing shutdown..can't reuse the same pool..as from the docs...executor will not accept new task..

Comment: Please read and understand the API of `ThreadpoolExecutor`. Do not wait in an infinite loop but use `awaitTermination`. If you want to execute several batches of tasks in the same `Threadpool` do not shutdown that pool but wait for `getActiveCount == 0` to become true